# Simple spring-boot application with pom.xml and app.java is showing build failed error

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

I am new in Java and I am trying to do a sample Spring Boot application. I am using eclipse IDE and Java 8. Created a Maven project with maven-archetype-quickstart archetype. In the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>StormpathSpringBoot</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>StormpathSpringBoot</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

 <properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

 </project>
```

In App.java

```
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
}
```

Then I run the application RunAs--> Maven Build
goal-> spring-boot:run

Don't know this is the right way to run this application

I am getting error

```
 2017-08-03 02:33:19.294  INFO 5124 --- [           main] com.demo.App                             : Starting App on C4968397007 with PID 5124 (C:\Users\dev3\WS_SpringBoot\StormpathSpringBoot\target\classes started by dev3 in C:\Users\dev3\WS_SpringBoot\StormpathSpringBoot)
 2017-08-03 02:33:19.297  INFO 5124 --- [           main] com.demo.App                             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
 2017-08-03 02:33:19.518  INFO 5124 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@39dcb4f0: startup date [Thu Aug 03 02:33:19 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-03 02:33:21.121  INFO 5124 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration; factoryMethodName=httpRequestHandlerAdapter; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]]
2017-08-03 02:33:21.950  INFO 5124 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fcd1a082] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-08-03 02:33:22.354  INFO 5124 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-03 02:33:22.369  INFO 5124 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
 2017-08-03 02:33:22.370  INFO 5124 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-08-03 02:33:22.471  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-08-03 02:33:22.472  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2954 ms
 2017-08-03 02:33:22.790  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-08-03 02:33:22.794  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-03 02:33:22.794  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
 2017-08-03 02:33:22.794  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-03 02:33:22.795  INFO 5124 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
 2017-08-03 02:33:23.157  WARN 5124 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'profileController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/dev3/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.6.3.RELEASE/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.6.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/ProfileController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistentEntities' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities]: Factory method 'persistentEntities' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

Comment: can you share this class ProfileController?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255169/spring-jpa-at-least-one-jpa-metamodel-must-be-present

Comment: where are your Entities?

Comment: I dont see the `<build> .... </build>` properties in you pom.xml, can you try adding that and see if it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring jpa - At least one JPA metamodel must be present\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255169/spring-jpa-at-least-one-jpa-metamodel-must-be-present)

Comment: @AmerQarabsa I havn't added any controllers yet. Is it required ?

Comment: Please upload full stack-trace so that we can help you.

Comment: @MehrajMalik  Updated the error log with some causes

Comment: @anas Tried adding <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build> but its not working

Comment: You do not have to add any controllers to start spring boot application. The problem is your data layer and Entity mappings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40738918/2819935

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run you can: in eclipse right click on project -> run as -> Java application

I use Eclipse based IDE STS - it is usually better for Spring as here initial configs are up to date and better tested

Error states, that there is no JPA mappings defined. You have to define them or delete depedndencies from POM

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are including `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` as a dependency. So there is a default controller with it (`ProfileController`), which is scanned at Spring context startup.

This controller has dependencies to other beans, one of which (`jpaMappingContext`) require a JPA configuration I guess.

Just remove this dependency and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

As already mention in comment/answer- You have added the dependency for Spring JPA but did not add any entities in the project. You can remove this and try.

`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 </dependency>`

Probably the best place to start a spring-boot project is to use spring initializr. 
https://start.spring.io/