# Spring 5 at least one JPA metamodel must be present

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have searched on StackOverflow for similar problems, and if I remove

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

everything works. However I need the data-jpa.

I have created 2 POJOs:

```
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

    public Author(){}
}
```

And the second one:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String isbn;
    private String publisher;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    public Book(String title, String isbn, String publisher) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
}
```

I have added 2 Entities and as I understand, I should no longer get the error `At least one JPA metamodel must be present`. Why I get this error?

**DemoApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My **pom.xml** dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am to low in reputation so i can't comment the question.

Can you share your full maven `pom.xml` please? The solution you are referencing is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305661/8089107) i guess? In this answer they do not recommend to remove `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` but to remove an explicit dependency to an "old" `spring-data-jpa`.

Make sure to share your pom file, i can only guess right now.

**Update:**

The dependencies `hibernate-core` and `hibernate-entititymanager` are already provided by `spring-boot-starter-jpa` and you override the managed versions with your custom versions which leads to your error.

Try to remove your explicit `hibernate-*` dependencies.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will update the question now

Comment: sorry for the delay. I was not on SO. Thank you!